# Split text into words with special characters

Tags: php

I am using this code to split a text into an array:

```
$wordArray = preg_split('#\PL+#u', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Altough this divides google.com into google and com, and what's into what and s. I have to admint preg_split is chinese to me, can you help with this?

Example:

```
$text = "What's google.com if not the best website in the world?";
foreach ($wordArray as $w) {
    echo $w.'<br>';
}

What
s
google
com
if
not
the
best
website
in
the
world

What I want is

    What's
    google.com
    if
    not
    the
    best
    website
    in
    the
    world
```

Comment: Can you add some sample strings with the expected results?

Comment: Can't you just simply use something like this `/[\s]+/`? Split up by space?

Comment: If you simply want to split it up on whitespace, do as Mahdi said. Otherwise, you'll have to preg_split on a list of specified characters. You may want to first strip off leading and trailing punctuation and whitespace, such as the ? at the end of the sentence, to avoid empty element(s) or elements such as "world?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not committed to using regexp, I've found it easier, personally, to split strings with the `explode()` function. It still splits into an array.

Example:

```
$wordArray = explode('.',$text);
```

Here's the manual page for it: http://www.php.net/explode

Comment: You totally misunderstood me. I edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: Use the explode() method with ' '. Only spaces will split your string in words. Example : var_dump(explode(' ',"What's up on google.com")) => [0]=>What's, [1]=>up [2]=>on [3]=>google.com

Comment: This is ok as well, but I heard that explode has issues, that's why I used preg_split

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_split('/[\s]+/', $sentence, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Use the `/[\s]+/` regex instead of the one you're using